# What view does Hinduism take of same sex union?

Tags: vedas, scripture, karma

Christianity and Islam detest same sex union or more accurately same sex marriage, I am not saying this but world over priests and imams are , I was curious if there is any mention of same sex union in the Hindu scriptures and do they disapprove or approve this move ?